# Extra double quotes appearing when concatenating in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to add double quotes while concatenating, and I am getting duplicate double quotes each time and wondering why.

```
=CONCATENATE("
SET @XML.modify('replace value of (/Cars/SedanCost/text())[1] with ",CHAR(34), TEXT(A12,"0.00"), CHAR(34), "');")
```

In this example my sentence will end up as :

```
SET @XML.modify('replace value of (/Cars/SedanCost/text())[1] with ""123456.00"");
```

Any idea how do I get a single double-quote (") instead of ("").

Thanks.

Comment: I tried your formula and I got exactly what you wanted, no double quotes (`""`). I used Excel 2013 - maybe your version of Excel has a bug.

Comment: @MarianD you could be right. This is weird

Comment: @MarianD made some changes. Apparently keying in 'Alt Enter' (new line for readability purposes as my full formula is really long) after the first double quote in Concatenate function, this double quote will  appear. You will need to paste the line over to notepad too. It will appear as correct in Excel. Please try. Thanks

Comment: I tried is as you told (Alt+Enter) an the result in Excel 2013 is still the same (correct, without double quotes). I also copy your now 2-line formula to the Notepad, then copy it from Notepad to the Excel cell, and still the same correct result. Something is wrong with your version of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your formula in Excel and it is working perfectly fine. Why not just use """" instead of CHAR(34)

Comment: Hi @Dennis Magno , tried that out too. Still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the use of the function `CONCATENATE` with direct concatenating by the operator `&`:

```
="SET @XML.modify('replace value of (/Cars/SedanCost/text())[1] with " & CHAR(34) & TEXT(A12,"0.00") & CHAR(34) & "');"
```

Comment: Hi @MarianD , I tried it out and it still doesnt work weirdly.

Comment: As two of us tried it and for us it worked as you wanted, probably it is the bug of your version of Excel. As I told, my version is 2013 (with all fixes-updated from Microsoft installed) and I got the correct result both for using `CONCATENATE` and `&`. So I'm sorry, I'm not able to help you. Maybe Microsoft is, try contact it.

Answer (score 0):

For your formula 
CONCATENATE("SET @XML.modify('replace value of (/Cars/SedanCost/text())[1] with """,CHAR(34),TEXT(A12,"0.00"),"""",""");")

Changes
with """,CHAR 

"0.00"),"""",""");")

Sample that can be reproduce and with more details:
=CONCATENATE(a1,a1,"This sum = 3 give "," ""double quote","this is additional quote at the end"," """)

Excel

A1 |  B1 |  c1                          | d1
 1 |   2 |  =IF(H8+I8 = 3,"""","blank") | Concatenate with the text above paste it on the cell d1